# bootstrap and jquery datatable, change button success to danger and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My jQuery DataTable loads buttons along with server side data, I am currently trying to make the buttons change colour and text, when I hover over them. At the moment all buttons are just set as `Active` when I hover over a button I want to remove the bootstrap `btn btn-success` and add `btn btn-danger` at the same time change the button text from `Active` to `Deactivate`.

**Script:**

```
  $('#example2').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "AdminPanel/AjaxHandler",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "aoColumns": [
                        { "sName": "ProviderId" },
                        { "sName": "CareServiceType" },
                        { "sName": "CareServiceName" },
                        { "sName": "Email" },
                        { "sName": "P" },
                        { "sName": "C" },
                        {
                            "sName": "blabla",
                            "targets": -1,
                            "data": null,
                            "defaultContent": "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Active</button>"
                        }
                    ]
    });
    $('#example2 tbody').on('hover', 'button', function () {
        removeClass("btn-success");
        addClass("btn-danger");
    });
```

Comment: You have a typo. It should be `btn-success` and `btn-danger` in your hover function.

Comment: Still doesnt do anything. But thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the jquery `mouseover` and `mouseout` events and bind them to body because the button will be added dynamically to the page.

See this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/eogz9k0o/2/

Comment: The actual **reason** why this is not working is because `hover` is not an event type (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).